# Css equally distribute table tr elements in 3 columns

Tags: css, css-tables

I am using tables. If I hide one or more 'tr' element, is there a way I can equally distribute tr in table again after hide, so for example here:

```
1   5   9
2   6   10
3   7   11
4   8   12
```

If I hide tr 6, can a 9,10,11,12 move one position back so I get this layout:

```
1   5   10
2   7   11
3   8   12
4   9
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v3uh6gr8/3/

Or, alternatively, what do you suggest to replicate this?, I dont need to use tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better option here is to use css multi-column layout and set `column-count: 3` which will do exactly what you want when you remove specific cell. Here is [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=column-count).

```js
document.getElementById("a1").onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("t6").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.element {
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  column-count: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
  <div class="cell">1</div>
  <div class="cell">2</div>
  <div class="cell">3</div>
  <div class="cell">4</div>
  <div class="cell">5</div>
  <div id="t6" class="cell">6</div>
  <div class="cell">7</div>
  <div class="cell">8</div>
  <div class="cell">9</div>
  <div class="cell">10</div>
  <div class="cell">11</div>
  <div class="cell">12</div>
</div>

<a id="a1" href="#">hide tr 6</a>
```